# Function runs before Button is Tapped, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have written a Function, which gets called, when a button is clicked. But this Code, which should be executed when the button is clicked, is gets executed in the build of the class...

This is my class:

```
class _home_ViewState extends State<EinkaufenView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RoundedButton(title: "PDF erstellen", colour: Colors.blue, onPressed: () {_createPDF();}
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Function:

```
Future<void> _createPDF () async {

  List<MaterialItem> liste = [
    MaterialItem(name: "Din A4 Heft", art: "Hefte", beschreibung: "Deine Mom", anzahl: 3, bildName: "")
  ];

  PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
  final page = document.pages.add();

  for(MaterialItem item in liste){
    page.graphics.drawString(item.name, PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 30));
  }

  List<int> bytes = document.save();
  document.dispose();

  saveAndLaunchFile(bytes, "PDF.pdf");
  print("Debug");
}
```

And this is the Button Layout, I used in the Class:

```
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RoundedButton(
      {required this.title, required this.colour, required this.onPressed});

  final Color colour;
  final String title;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: onPressed(),
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also built in a print Statement in my Function, which also gets executed on Appear of the View...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the function is being invoked in the `build` method because of the way `onPressed` is handled in the `build` method of `RoundedButton`, the `()` in the  `MaterialButton.onPressed` needs to be removed as it invokes the function, where you want a reference to the function.

Update the code to read like the example below

```dart
 MaterialButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
...
)
```

You could also follow the same pattern in `_home_ViewState`, since you don't need to pass any arguments to `_createPDF`, you can update the code to read.

```
onPressed: _createPDF
```

if you do need to pass data to the function, then you use the `() => _createPDF(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine but here only one problem is in thins line

```
onPressed: onPressed(),
```

you are calling the method instead of placing the instance of it.

So change this line to

```
onPressed: onPressed,
```

and it will eork

```
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RoundedButton(
      {required this.title, required this.colour, required this.onPressed});

  final Color colour;
  final String title;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
          // you must place the function like this
          onPressed: onPressed,
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```